# Question about generalized eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

I was marked off for this answer and cannot see why.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Prove if $T\in \mathcal{L}(V)$ $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{F}$ $\alpha \neq \beta$,

$G(\alpha,T)+G(\beta,T)=G(\alpha,T)\oplus G(\beta,T)$ where $G(\lambda,T)$ denotes the generalized eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$.

My Proof:

Prove $G(\alpha,T)\cap G(\beta,T)=\{0\}$

Assume by way of contradiction $v \neq 0$ and
$v \in G(\alpha,T)\cap G(\beta,T)$

Thus $v$ is a generalized eigenvector corresponding to $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Since $\alpha \neq \beta$ this implies the list $v,v$ is linearly independent.

But since $v,v$ is linearly dependent, our assumption that $v \neq 0$ must be false.

Thus $G(\alpha,T)\cap G(\beta,T)=\{0\}$

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with your reasoning, although the point deduction might have to do with how you skipped steps, or used results unproven in class (have you proven in class that generalized eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent? although this is true, it is not equivalent to the fact that regular eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent).

Comment: we proved that generalized eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Comment: hmm in that case I'm not sure :/ Did you try asking your prof/TA? What did they say?

Comment: I'll probably ask. Thanks for your input.